# Perl and closures. Is it possible to?

Tags: perl, closures

To write closure in Perl we need to write

```
sub test {
    my( $x, $y, $z ) =  @_;

    my $closure =  sub{ $x + $y + $z };
}
```

But sometimes, if not always, the subroutine may have many lines, and I would like to take the subroutine's definition outside and use something like this

```
my $z;

sub test {
    my( $x, $y ) =  @_;

    my $closure =  closure( 'subname', $x, $y, $z );
}

sub subname : closure ( $var1, $var2, $var3 ) {
    $var1 + $var2 + $var3
}
```

So I can reuse this closure from elsewhere

```
my $on2;

sub test_xxx {
    my( $other_name1, $on3 ) =  @_;

    my $closure =  closure( 'subname', $on3, $other_name1, $on2 );
}
```

Is this possible in Perl?

Comment: This sort of thing is often called a "factory", and it's something I write about quite a bit in [Intemediate Perl](https://www.intermediateperl.com) and [Mastering Perl](https://www.masteringperl.org).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
use 5.012;
use warnings;

my $z;
sub test
{
    my ($x, $y) = @_;

    return sub { complicated_code($x, $y, $z) };
}

my $on2;
sub test_xxx
{
    my ($other_name1, $on3) =  @_;

    return sub { complicated_code($on3, $other_name1, $on2) };
}

sub complicated_code
{
    my ($a, $b, $c) = @_;

    return $a + $b + $c;
}

$z = 42;
my $closure = test(2,3);
say $closure->();       # 47
$z = 1;
say $closure->();       # 6

my $closure_xxx = test_xxx(4,5);
$on2 = 23;
say $closure_xxx->();   # 32
```

In other words, put your complicated code with many lines in a regular `sub`, and simply call this `sub` in your closure.

Comment: Could you please explain what your code is doing and how/why it is different than the OPs question for those who may not understand what you've posted?

Comment: @stevieb, The OP uses pseudocode; mscha provided an implementation. But they also changed all the names, makeing it hard to see the parallel. That's why I posted my answer, which is really just a rewording of mscha's.

Answer (score 4):

`closure` would be defined as follows:

```
sub closure {
    my ($sub_name, @args) = @_;
    my $sub = \&$subname;
    return sub { $sub->(@args) };
}
```

But this indirection isn't helpful. Instead, simply replace

```
my $closure = closure( 'subname', $x, $y, $z );

my $closure = closure( 'subname', $on3, $other_name1, $on2 );
```

with

```
my $closure = sub { subname($x, $y, $z) };

my $closure = sub { subname($on3, $other_name1, $on2) };
```

If you did need a helper, it wouldn't be so generic. It would usually have some task-specific prep code followed by a `return sub { };`

```
sub make_foo_iter {
   my @args = @_;
   # ...
   return sub {
      # ...
   };
}

my $iter = make_foo_iter(...);
```